# Trace back to certain indiviuals

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data and my issue is the following: at some point of time and at a certain place, a contamination  occurs. I don't know who caused it but I want to be able to trace this back with the largest likelihood possible. I need a probability for each individual to be the cause of this contamination. This is what the desired column "Prob_Contiminator" should show.

I know certain times at which a note was made about an occured contamination but this is only the time where the contamination was reported. What I have in mind is a high probability of having caused the contamination if someone is temporally close to the ocurrence, which decreases the further away the observation of an individual is from the contamination.

It is important that only individuals are considered to have caused the contamination if they have the same location_id as the occurence row had. Another problem is that people who frequently appear in the data would automatically apear to have caused the contamination more often. I additionally have data on when cleaning occured. I thought about limiting the observations of these "frequent users" to one observation which is closest to the event within one cleaning interval. How do I manage to properly spot the contaminators without discriminating the people who happen to be "heavy users"?

Data:

```
"Event_ID" "Person_ID" "Note"    "time"       "location_id" "Cleaning"
1           1           ""        1990-01-01   1             1
2           1           ""        1990-01-02   1             0
3           2           ""        1990-01-03   1             0
4           3           "Occured" 1993-01-03   1             1
5           3           ""        1995-01-04   2             0
6           3           ""        1995-01-04   2             0
7           4           ""        1995-01-04   3             0
8           5           ""        1995-01-05   6             0
9           6           ""        1995-01-05   5             0
10          7           "Ocurred" 1995-01-05   6             1
```

This is what I need ( Prob_Contaminator column not complete):

```
 "Event_ID" "Person_ID" "Note"    "time"       "location_id" "Cleaning" "Prob_Contaminator"
1           1           ""        1990-01-01    1             1          0.4
2           1           ""        1990-01-02    1             0          0.4
3           2           ""        1990-01-03    1             0          0.6
4           3           "Occured" 1993-01-03    1             1
5           3           ""        1995-01-04    2             0
6           3           ""        1995-01-04    2             0
7           4           ""        1995-01-04    3             0
8           5           ""        1995-01-05    6             0
9           6           ""        1995-01-05    5             0
10          7           "Ocurred" 1995-01-05    6             1
```

The following example shows how I imagine the column Prob_Contaminated to be constructed. If we consider the row number 4 (Event ID=4), we see that a contamination has occured. Now i want to look back at all events since the last cleaning (in this case 3 events, based on the cleaning taken place at event_ID =1) and consider how far they are away from the event of contamination. This should only occur under the condition that the events looked at take place in the same location_id. Since the location_id is the same in this example (=1), the probability of being the contaminator for these 3 events is 1/3. Multiple events of 1 person should be reduced to the time closest to the contamination. This reduces the cases to two, and ergo the probability for Person_ID 1 and Person_ID 2 to be 1/2. Additionally I want to weight each probability by the distance that they have  to the contamination. Since "time" value of Person_ID=2 is closer to the row with contamination than the the "time" value of Person_ID=1, the Prob_Contaminated for Person_ID=2 should be weighted higher. In this case I applied a weight of 1.2 for the more "recent" ID to the event (1.2*0.5=0.6) and a weight of 0.8*0.5=0.4) to the less recent event.

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(Event_ID = c(1:10),
                 Person_ID = c("1","1","2","3","3","3","4","5","6","7"),
                 Note = c("","","","Occured","","","","","","Ocurred"),
                 time = as.Date(c('1990-1-1','1990-1-2','1990-1-3','1993-1-3','1995-1-4','1995-1-4','1995-1-4',"1995-1-5","1995-1-5","1995-1-5")),
                 location_id = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","3","6","5","6"),
                 Cleaning  = c("1","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","1"))

df2 <- data.frame(Event_ID = c(1:10),
                 Person_ID = c("1","1","2","3","3","3","4","5","6","7"),
                 Note = c("","","","Occured","","","","","","Ocurred"),
                 time = as.Date(c('1990-1-1','1990-1-2','1990-1-3','1993-1-3','1995-1-4','1995-1-4','1995-1-4',"1995-1-5","1995-1-5","1995-1-5")),
                 location_id = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","3","6","5","6"),
                 Cleaning  = c("1","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","1"),
                 Prob_Contiminator  = c("0.4","0.4","0.6","","","","","","",""))
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to get. Can you maybe show the perfect result to after we do something with your data? It would be great if you could explain the heuristics like first, we filter all the locations, then for each location we look for the first occurrence of the value "Occurred" (or cleaning that equals 1? Bit confused here), and then output all the first occurrences?

Comment: @AlexeyKnorre Thank you for your feedback. I added the desired output, explained an example of the first 3 rows and clarified the question..

Comment: Maybe you can write down the formula for the probabilty of contamination? Something like ProbCont = Number_of_days_after_last_cleaning * ... / Number_of_people_on_the_same_location ? That would be much easier to comprehend. Now I am not sure I still understand how you calculate the probability.